# Geometry node - How to compare differente values in a field

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, loop

I make a simple exemple for me problem.

[image]

I have a GN object with limited integrer random value for Z position (or anything) , I want compare this values for delete the instance with the same value. I suppose that the best way is to transform  array to enter in the "selection" socket of "instance points" node.

In JS, I Think something like this

```
const GeometryNodeToto.valueZ = [5, 1, 1, 5, 4];

for (let i = 0; i <GeometryNodeToto.valueZ.length; i++) 
{
    valueI = GeometryNodeToto.valueZ[i];
    valueJ = GeometryNodeToto.valueZ[j];
    
    for (j = 0; j <GeometryNodeToto.valueZ.length; j++)
        {if (valueI  ==  valueJ)
            {
                GeometryNodeToto.valueZ[j] = false;
            }

        }
  }
```

Is it possible in GN ???

Thanks for your help. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Accumulate Field*'s *Group Index* to see that the *Group Index* is already in use:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The node "accumulate field" is exactly the solution to my problem.